# Basis for Ker(T) and Image(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to find a basis for $\text{Ker}(T)$ and the $\text{Image(T)}$

$T∶ P_2 (\mathbb{R})→ P_2 (\mathbb{R})$  defined by $T(a+bx+cx^2 )=(-2b+11c)+(-2a+c)x+(3a-b+4c)x^2$

I know I have to set $-2b+11c = 0$, $-2a+c = 0$, $3a-b+4 = 0$, but where do the x's come into play?  Can I set up a matrix with the coefficients and row reduce to get the x's or $a,b,c$?  I am a little lost any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: $x$ is not an unknown to be solved for.  It's a variable.  You can think of $1$, $x$, and $x^2$ as a basis of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Another phrasing of the previous comment: this is exactly the same problem as if you had a function $U\colon \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ defined by $U((a,b,c)) = (-2b+11c,-2a+c,3a-b+4c)$. That might help see why there shouldn't be any $x$s in your matrix.

Comment: So the x's are only to signify that a linear transformation from V -> W will have bases for the kernal and the image that spans the variables.  But what if the transformation is from a 2x2 Matrix to polynomial degree 3, will the bases for the kernal and image be in the form of a matrix or $\{1, x, x^2, x^3]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T(1)=-2x+3x^2, \;\;T(x)=-2-x^2, \;\;T(x^2)=11+x+4x^2$,

we can reduce the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-2&11\\-2&0&1\\3&-1&4\end{bmatrix}$ to get $R=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-\frac{1}{2}\\0&1&-\frac{11}{2}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

1) Solving $Rx=0$ gives $x=t, y=11t, z=2t$; so the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\11\\2\\\end{bmatrix}$ is a basis for the kernel of R,
and

$\;\;\;$therefore $\{1+11x+2x^2\}$ is a basis for Ker(T).

2) A basis for the column space of A is given by its first 2 columns (since they correspond to the leading 1's $\;\;\;$in R), and therefore $\{-2x+3x^2, -2-x^2\}$ is a basis for Image(T).